# Types for bracket notation in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create one redux action for some routine state updates and wondering if it's possible to make types work for bracket notation:

```js
interface IThing {
  someProp: string;
  otherProp: boolean;
}

const state = {
  thing: {
    someProp: 'prop',
    otherProp: true,
  } as IThing
}

const action = { name: 'someProp' as keyof IThing, value: 'someValue' as any }

// gives typescript error: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'
state.thing[action.name] = action.value;
```

Comment: What's draft? What's thing?

Comment: @ritaj see [this](https://techinscribed.com/clean-react-architecture-with-redux-immer-typescript-redux-observable/) for reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ritaj you're right, it's not actually redux or immer related, going to update description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that if you're assigning a value by a dynamic property name, then the value on the right-hand side needs to be assignable to any property you might name. In this case that means it must be assignable to both `string` and `boolean`, which means it must be of type `never` (since the two types have no common values).

The solution is to use a generic type, so that you can constrain the property name to be of type `K`, and the value you assign can be of type `IThing[K]` which is not necessarily `never`. Here's an example:

```js
interface IAction<K extends keyof IThing> {
  name: K;
  value: IThing[K];
}

function assign<K extends keyof IThing>(thing: IThing, action: IAction<K>): void {
  thing[action.name] = action.value;
}

const action = { name: 'someProp', value: 'someValue' } as const;
assign(state.thing, action); // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUAWoDmyDeAUMsgM4D2AthAApTkAOAXGWFLgNzHLlibR1GLAEblyAGwhwQXAL6FCCciFJhWcSMgC8Bbn1wsiJEhWqDmyAOQN6DSwBpuJXvyjmWbAK4RHJWcjhSNCxcQnlCUEhYRBRUAEEEMGBlAB4AaWQIAA9IEAATIIBrCABPchhg7BAcAD5dEhA4ahY0rhIANzhxbxYMKpwAbTSAXTkFGE8QROSQANJSYBwQdMyciHyi0vLK3BqACn1q3pDq+wDp5V6EpNS0moBKFnbyYDz65EPBxBuQADpG6jDbTnH6-TrdCBjRTKVQgmbA-DIAEQFiWUy0WwOZDgnpWdEANS63ksyH8gWQShUYC4gQWSz2qg0EF+nzO3xm9w4yAA9NyeIVCEA)